# Pycharm doesn't show "executable_path" and I got this error and no idea what to do

Tags: window

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Soe Htet Oo\PycharmProjects\PythonTesting\PythonSelenium\demoBrowser.py", line 3, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

I am just beginner and I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `executable_path` is an argument of `webdriver.chrome.service.Service`, see [ducumentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver)
Just use

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# or
service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(executable_path='path/to/your/chrome/driver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```